# conditional variance theorem?

Tags: probability

I need to show that $V(X)=V(E(X|Y))+E[V(X|Y)]$

So then $V(E(X|Y))=E((Y-E(E(X|Y))^2)=E(Y^2-2YE(E(X|Y))+E(E(X|Y))^2)=E(Y^2)-2E(Y)E(X)+E(X)^2$

$E(V(X|Y))=E(E((Y-E(X|Y))^2))=E(Y^2-2YE(X)+E(X|Y)^2)$

I'm not sure how to cancel everything after.

Comment: This looks like Eve's Law, or the law of total variance. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QXMi7i0cYiE) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that
$$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}
\begin{align}
\Var(\E(X\mid Y))
&=\E\left(\E(X\mid Y)^2\right)-\E(\E(X\mid Y))^2\\
&=\E\left(\E(X\mid Y)^2\right)-\E(X)^2\tag1
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\Var(X\mid Y)=\E\left(X^2\mid Y\right)-\E(X\mid Y)^2\tag2
$$
and taking the expectation of $(2)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
\E(\Var(X\mid Y))
&=\E\left(\E\left(X^2\mid Y\right)\right)-\E\left(\E(X\mid Y)^2\right)\\
&=\E\left(X^2\right)-\E\left(\E(X\mid Y)^2\right)\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Adding $(1)$ and $(3)$ gives [The Law of Total Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance):
$$
\begin{align}
\Var(\E(X\mid Y))+\E(\Var(X\mid Y))
&=\E\left(X^2\right)-\E(X)^2\\
&=\Var(X)\tag4
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I see that I proved The Law of Total Variance in $(3)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/69607), as well.